# Do Mongoose query calls throw exceptions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have several interesting questions. I am using mongoose and node.js
Let's imagine I have a schema called Actor and all questions will be about it.

1) `const saveActor = await Actor.save();`

Does this throw an exception all the time or is it mandatory and precaution to check it like the following? :

```
if(saveActor) return "success"; else return "error"; ?
```

2) `const actor = Actor.findByIdAndUpdate("5ca509acd0ddef4d1c1c892f", someotheroptions);`

If not found, it returns null. So, I must check if it returns null - Does it mean the document was not found? What about the update? What if update doesn't work - Does it throw an exception all the time or does it sometimes return null?

3) What about other mongoose functions? `findByIdAndRemove`? what is the sum up? Do they throw exceptions all the time or sometimes? I can't find this information in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: `const saveActor = await Actor.save()`.

`saveActor` will contain the success return value. If error occurred, it'll throw and error which you've to catch; for `async/await` syntax it's done like:

```
try {
  const saveActor = await Actor.save();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

2: `const actor = Actor.findByIdAndUpdate("5ca509acd0ddef4d1c1c892f", someotheroptions)`

If the query was successful:

1. there was no matching entry, then it will return null. *So, I must check if it returns null - Does it mean the document was not found?* -> Yes
2. if a match was found, it will return the successfull operation value (the document which was updated)

If error occurred, throws an error. If you're using `callback`, error will be passed to the callback as param. If you're using `thenables` or `Promise`/`async await` then you'll have to `catch`.

3: Different method have different return type. For example (from docs):

```
Mongoose.prototype.model()
Returns:

  «Model» The model associated with name. Mongoose will create the model if it doesn't already exist.

Model.find()
Returns:

  «Query»
```

**Errors**

As for errors, in general, if the method accepts callback, error is a parameter like `(err, doc) => { if (err) console.error(err) ... }`

If you're not passing callback, then it's usually `thenables` or `Promise` ([more here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)). It's handled like `Actor.findByIdAndUpdate("5ca509acd0ddef4d1c1c892f", someotheroptions).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.error(err))` etc.

Full [mongoose API](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html). Refer MDN for [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Thanks  For your help. Btw, could you also look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503657/how-to-treat-any-kind-of-error-globally-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

Q1: await Actor.save() will throw an error

Q2/Q3: You can use [orFail()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-orFail) like so:

```
await Actor.findByIdAndUpdate("5ca509acd0ddef4d1c1c892f", someotheroptions).orFail();
```

Or:

```
await Actor.findByIdAndUpdate("5ca509acd0ddef4d1c1c892f", someotheroptions).orFail(new Error('Document not found'));
```